# Is 請 also mean "to treat" in Mandarin?

Tags: mandarin

I answered a question about the character 請,  http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?14,137964,137965#msg-137965 on other site.

In Cantonese, 請 can mean: "to treat; to pay for someone" beside the listed meanings of " to invite" in the dictionary on that site.

I suddenly realized it may not be the case in Mandarin, I think I heard Mandarin say: 「這頓飯我作東」, 「這頓飯我來付」，but do Mandarin say 「這頓飯我來請」 or  「我今晚請吃晚飯」？

Comment: Yes. It's short for "请客" in this kind of scenario. "请客" means _invite someone(to some place) to have a treat_.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense, I have updated my answer on the other site. *請 means " to treat" only as a short form of "請客", but not the character itself.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

These phrases 『这顿饭我来请』『今天我请客』『我请』 very common in Mandarin.